# RabbitMQ failed to start with a custom config file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ on Ubuntu and everything is working, but when I try to change the Management plugin listening port, I can't start the RabbitMQ server anymore.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart
[....] Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl): rabbitmq-server.serviceJob for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

Here is what the startup log says:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",generate_config_file}
```

And here is my rabbitmq.conf file:

```
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.tcp.port = 80
```

rabbitmq-plugins list command:

```
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache       3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http        3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.7.8
[E ] rabbitmq_management               3.7.8
[E ] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws       3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common    3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_consul    3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_etcd      3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s       3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_random_exchange          3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.7.8
[e ] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples        3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.7.8
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.7.8
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have another service working on port `80`? `Nginx` or `Apache`

Comment: No, I don't. The error occurs regardless of the port I set, event the default (15672).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run RabbitMQ management using port `80`, but RabbitMQ runs as the non-privileged user `rabbitmq`, which is not allowed to bind to port `80`.

The easiest solution is to run on the default port `15672` and use a proxy to serve on port `80`.